# Помогите пожалуйста, файл не сохраняется

Tags: xml, xsd

Вроде все правильно написал, но выдает ошибку. Говорят, удалите `<xs:simpleType>` Но зачем? Написал все как в книге. Вот xml файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<productdata xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///C:/Users/guest/Desktop/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D2%9B/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BD/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B1/8%20%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0/product.xsd">
    <product category="toy" prodid="t001">
        <productname> Stupid Casual: Имаджинариум </productname>
        <description> 
            «Имаджинариум» — это очень простая и очень интересная игра, в которой нужно придумывать ассоциации к необычным картинкам из коробки.
        </description>
        <price> 9899 </price>
        <quantity> 26 </quantity>
    </product>
    <product category="book" prodid="b001">
        <productname> Богатый папа, бедный папа </productname>
        <description> 
            Научите детей обращаться с деньгами раньше, чем они столкнутся с материальными трудностями в нашем нестабильном мире! 
        </description>
        <price> 4230 </price>
        <quantity> 22 </quantity>
    </product>
</productdata>
```

xsd код:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="productdata">
        <xs:complexType >
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="product" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="productname" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="price" type="xs:integer"/>
                            <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:integer"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="prodid" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="category" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>

        <xs:simpleType name="cat">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value="toy|book"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Можете сказать в чем проблема?

Comment: В какой программе не сохраняется и какой именно из файлов - xsd или xml ?

Answer (score 0):

У вашего XSD есть две проблемы.

(1) Атрибуты были в неправильном месте.
(2) `<xs: simpleType>` висел в воздухе.

Обе проблемы были исправлены. Вот исправленный XSD.
Файл XML теперь корректно проверяется на соответствие XSD.

> XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="productdata">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="product" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="productname" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="price" type="xs:integer"/>
                            <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:integer"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="prodid" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                        <xs:attribute ref="category" use="required"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:attribute name="category">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value="toy|book"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
</xs:schema>
```